# SQL server Suma mas Distinct

Tags: sql

Necesito sumar el campo `CantidadIngresa` para cada producto diferente, la suma se realiza correctamente.

Por ejemplo en el producto "GAZ" si sumo (4+5+2) = 11, esto es correcto, sin embargo necesito que me muestre cada producto una sola vez, pero a pesar de que uso la instrucción `Distinct` para que me muestre solo una linea por cada producto, me sigue mostrando los productos tantas veces como se repita. En el caso del ejemplo del GAZ, debería mostrarse solo 1 vez.
Que es lo que estoy haciendo mal?

Instrucción SQL:

```
select Distinct (NombreProd), CantidadAnterior, sum(CantidadIngresa) over(partition by NombreProd) as resultado
from TBHistoricoProductos
```

Agradecería cualquier sugerencia!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

intenta agregarle

```
GROUP BY NombreProd;
```

esto te ayuda a que no se muestren todos repetidos.lo que pasa es que el distinct te quita los repetidos pero dentro del query tenes mas resultados que no van a ser obviados directamente por el distinct, como la suma.

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas utilizar `over ()` aquí. Como [Julian Cuevas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/101813/julian-cuevas) te recomienda intenta con `group by` y ya que esttarías agrupando por producto, tampoco necesitas utilizar `distinct`. Además creo que deberías agregar la cantidad anterior también. Quedaría algo así:

```
select NombreProd
     , sum(CantidadAnterior) as Total_Cant_Ant
     , sum(CantidadIngresa) as Total_Cant_Ingr

from TBHistoricoProductos

group by NombreProd
```

Incluso podrias incluir alguna fecha y agrupar también por fecha. Quizás mensual.

```
select trunc(Fecha, 'mm') Mes
     , NombreProd
     , sum(CantidadAnterior) as Total_Cant_Ant
     , sum(CantidadIngresa) as Total_Cant_Ingr

from TBHistoricoProductos

group by trunc(Fecha, 'mm')
       , NombreProd

order by Mes, NombreProd
```